# Deadlock while using async/await

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

I'm trying to understand `await` and `async`.

It works very well. But now I have a deadlock.

I've called `ConfigureAwait` with `false`, like in [this article](http://blog.ciber.no/2014/05/19/using-task-configureawaitfalse-to-prevent-deadlocks-in-async-code/), but my code is still blocking.

Here's a little snippet of my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = HeavyWorkAsync().Result;
    richTextBox1.AppendText(result);
}

private string HeavyWork()
{
    for (var index = 0; index < 1000; index++)
    {
        Task.Delay(10).Wait();
    }

    return "finished";
}

private async Task<string> HeavyWorkAsync()
{
    var task = await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(HeavyWork).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return task;
}
```

Comment: can you explain why you dont want to do `await HeavyWorkAsync()` ?

Comment: In my opinion, it's ugly. Async in the click handler of a button?

Comment: It is the recommended way to handle this scenario and on top of that it's not blocking or deadlocking :)

Comment: On top? What is this doing else, if this is no deadlock, like in the article?

Comment: `async void` is legal precisely to handle this kind of case. Yes, `async void` is ugly and should be avoided in every signature that is not a subscribtion to an event, but we have no choice because the UI framework we use does not support proper async callbacks.

Comment: @MarcelHoffmann your code wouldn't deadlock, the code in the article works in that respect. Although it would still block the UI for 10 seconds, due to handling `var result = HeavyWorkAsync().Result;` on the UI thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's blocking is not the task itself, it's the call to `Result`. A `Task` represents an asynchronous operation, but calling its `Result` property, or calling `Wait()` will block the current thread until the method returns. And in a lot of cases, it will cause a deadlock because the task is not able to complete with it's calling thread blocked!

To prevent that, chain the tasks asynchronously, using `async` and `await`

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await HeavyWorkAsync(); // <=== await
    richTextBox1.AppendText(result);
}
```

Also, `Task.Delay(10).Wait();` completely defeats the prupose of using tasks in the first place: that will block the current thread. If that's **really** what you want to do (and it's pretty unlikely), call `Thread.Sleep(10);`instead, it will make your intent much clearer, and you will have less hoops to jump through. Or better, use `await Task.Delay(10);`in an async method.

### About `ConfigureAwait`

What exactly does `ConfigureAwait(false)` do?

It removes the obligation for the continuation of the task to run in the same context as the caller of the task. In most cases that means that the continuation is no longer guaranteed to run on the same context. So if I have a method thad does `Foo()`, waits a little then `Bar()` like this one:

```
async Task DoStufAsync()
{
    Foo();
    await Task.Delay(10);
    Bar(); // run in the same context as Foo()
}
```

I'm guaranteed Bar will run in the same context. If I had `ConfigureAwait(false)`, it's no longer the case

```
async Task DoStufAsync()
{
    Foo();
    await Task.Delay(10).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Bar(); // can run on another thread as Foo()
}
```

When you're using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, you tell your program you dont mind about the context. It can solve some deadlocking problems, but isn't usually the right solution. The right solution is most likely never to wait for tasks in a blocking way, and being asynchronous all the way.

Comment: Note that the article / OP is attempting to use `ConfigureAwait` to avoid having to make the click handler `async` in the first place.

Comment: The problem is `ConfigureAwait` doesn't do that: the UI thread will become unresponsive because of the call to `Result` regardless of the internal workings of the methods. The best he can hope for is have a huge ugly freeze that will eventually finish instead of an infinite deadlock.

Comment: Could you explain that in your answer to complete it then since it's the main focus of the question - I'm fairly new to async stuff myself, but it seems that the article is implying that it's possible to use it in this way

Comment: @JamesThorpe : I certainly can, and will right now!

Comment: Ok, I think I've understand it. If I use this code in a non-ui thread, then should work my code, right?

Comment: @MarcelHoffmann : yes, it will work, but you will still be blocking a thread needlessly. Threads are a precious resource, don't waste them.

Comment: Okay, thanks for you're answer. The better way is for example calling an event, right? This solution is non blocking.

Comment: `await` does not resume on the same thread; it resumes on the same *context*. A UI context has a one-to-one relationship with a thread, but other contexts (e.g., ASP.NET, thread pool, etc) do not.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Falanwe's answer, you should check out [Stephen Cleary's blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Based off of the code I'm assuming that you are using a Windows Forms application, so a call to Task.Result will execute the task on the UI context, which in turn blocks the UI thread.